# SQL Joins - Why does this simple join work, despite the syntax making no sense?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've read numerous tutorials and graphical representations of MySQL joins, and they still don't make sense to me.

I'm trying to type my own now, and they are working, but I just don't see how they're working.

Take this set of tables

```
images                           squares
----------------------------     ----------------------------------
image_id |  name | square_id     square_id |  latitude |  longitude
----------------------------     ----------------------------------
1         someImg    14          1            42.333      24.232
2         newImg     3           2            38.322      49.2320
3         blandImg   76          3            11.2345     99.4323
...                              ...
n                                n
```

This is a one to many relationship - one square can have many images, but an image can only have one square.

Now I run this simple join, but I'm not understanding the syntax of it at all...

```
SELECT images.image_id 
FROM squares
LEFT JOIN images ON images.square_id=squares.square_id 
WHERE images.square_id=711464;
```

Now, this actually works, which amazes me. It brings up a list of images within the square range.

But I'm having a hard time understanding the `ON` syntax.

- **What does `ON` do exactly?**
- **Does it show how the two tables are related?**

Mainly however, `SELECT images.image_id FROM squares`, makes the least sense.

**How can I select a field in one table but `FROM` another?**

Comment: You're not selecting from `squares` your selecting from the results of joining squares and images (so fields from both tables are available). The `ON` is indeed the rule for combining the tables.

Comment: If it helps, imagine brackets around the clause starting immediately after FROM and ending before WHERE. The result of that is the table you're selecting from (and applying the WHERE too).

Comment: This is basic JOIN syntax. Any SQL tutorial should explain how it works.

Comment: @SpaceDog Yep, the brackets help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the `FROM` clause, which in it's entirety is:

```
FROM squares LEFT JOIN images ON images.square_id=squares.square_id
```

(it's not just `FROM squares`).
This defines the source of your data. You specify both tables, `squares` and `images` so they are both sources for the data that the query will work on.
Next, you use the `on` syntax to explain how this tables are related to one another. `images.square_id=squares.square_id` means: consider a row in the `images` table related to a row in the `squares` table  if and only if the value of the field `square_id` of the `images` row is equal to the value of the field `square_id` of the `squares` table. At this moment, each row of the result is a combination of a row from the `images` table and a row from the `squares` table (I'll ignore the `LEFT JOIN` at the moment).

Next, you have the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE images.square_id=711464
```

This means, from the rows that are in result set, just get those where the value of the `square_id` field, in that part of the result row that came from the images table, is exactly `711464`.

And last comes the `SELECT` part.

```
SELECT images.image_id
```

This means, from the rows that are in the result set (a combination of a `square` row and a `images` row), take just the field `image_id` that is from the `images` table.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. I was breaking the query up into little chunks instead of examining the FROM...LEFT JOIN...ON segment as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the query as such:

```
SELECT images.image_id FROM
    squares LEFT JOIN images
        ON images.square_id=squares.square_id
WHERE
    images.square_id=711464
```

So you first join the `squares` table with the `images` table, combining entries in `images` which have the same `square_id` as in the `squares` table. So, the `ON` syntax is actually specifying the condition on which the two tables should be joined.

Then, you do a filter using `WHERE`, which will take the entries with `square_id=711464`

Note that by the time you do the `SELECT`, you already joined the two tables, which will have the combined fields:

```
images
--------------------------------------------------
square_id | latitude | longitude | image_id | name
--------------------------------------------------
```

So, you can select the `square_id` from the resulting table.

Answer (score 0):

It is more like :

```
SELECT images.image_id FROM (squares LEFT JOIN images ON images.square_id=squares.square_id WHERE images.square_id=711464)
```

So you don't select a field from another table - it is more like you create a new temporary table from the statement in brackets (actually having columns from multiple tables) and then perform `SELECT` on this table.

And yes, `ON` defines how the tables are related (for instance with foreign key)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [COLUMNS] --First Line Of Code - say it as 1
FROM --Second Line Of Code -- say it as 2 
[Table1] Join [table2] On [Criteria] --say it as 3
Where [Some More Criteria] --Say it as 4
```

Whenever a

```
Select Column From
```

is  done it gets the data from 3 which is collection of multiple table or single table.

Once the data is loaded it Executes the where criteria for filtering the data.
After data filtration Select statement will be Executed.

In your case:
Left Join will execute and generate table with 6 columns. based on Join Criteria. Than Where criteria will be executed to filter the data.

Select statement execution will takes place only after that.

Regarding using the Table Name as prefix is to avoid the conflict in Column Name.

P.S : This is for your understanding, actually the data load doesn't happen. To understand exactly how queries are executed you need to understand DB Engine.
As Of Now,Write query and leave the DB Engine for planning.

With Experience Comes The Knowledge.

Happy Coding